# Android: Why the tab layout all fragment is get refreshed when i open one particular tab

Tags: android

I having 3 Tabs. When I open the first tab, it refreshed all 3 tabs unnecessarily. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: First Display your code, that time only we given suggestions/answers

Comment: Are you using Viewpager or something? Show your code

Comment: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0); if you are using viewpager

Comment: am using view pager. Also used viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);  already

Comment: then post your code for more details

Comment: My issue is, i having activity one. On click from that activity one, it moves to the other activity two contains 3 tabs. So while intent from activity one to activity two, it loads all the 3 tabs in activity two

Comment: it is the default behaviour. you have to write your code in onPageSelected() of viewpager listener.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  update your query as per this .Where you will  get answer directly instead of too many questions

Answer (score 0):

use `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`.It will cache two views on the right and two on the left and wont load them again and gain

Answer (score 0):

setOffscreenPageLimit(0) is useless. if you set it less than 1,it will be set to 1 according by source code.

```
 public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
    if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small;  defaulting to " +
                DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
        limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
    }
    if (limit != mOffscreenPageLimit) {
        mOffscreenPageLimit = limit;
        populate();
    }
}
```

and the DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES is:

```
 private static final int DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES = 1;
```

here are my suggestions:
using reflection to set the mOffscreenPageLimit with value 0;

refreshing fragment at your OnPageChangeListener's onPageSelected instead of refreshing it at fragment:
at OnPageChangeListener:

```
private OnPageChangeListener mOnPageChangeListener = new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //put your refreshing code here.
    }
};
```

at fragment's onCreateView():

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(is default page that selected){
        //put your refresh code here.
    }
}
```

last,making a copy of ViewPage.java, change DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES with value 0.

either of then can solve your problem.